# JSON decode for inconsistent array using php

Tags: php, android, json

I have an android app which is send me data thats something like this-

```
{"uid":1, "newAdd":"New York", "coupon_status":"yes", "coupon_code":"SALE50", "place_code":4, "basket":[{"name":"xyz", "vendorId":1, "total":100, "count":2}, {...} ,{...}] }
```

I need to decode this and use the data to store into the database. How do i use a loop to use these data. I have done normal array but this has an object inside it.

Please help.

PHP only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSONObject](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) and [JSONArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html) to fetch data from JSON String.

You've JSON **Object** string as follow.

```
{"uid":1, "newAdd":"New York", "coupon_status":"yes", "coupon_code":"SALE50", "place_code":4, "basket":[{"name":"xyz", "vendorId":1, "total":100, "count":2}, {...} ,{...}] }
```

You can convert this to **JSONObject** object by calling,

```
JSONObject myObject=new JSONObject(YOUR_JSON_STRING);
```

Now to retrieve values from **JSONObject** there are several method available.

[getString()](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getString(java.lang.String)) - To get string value.
[getInt()](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getInt(java.lang.String)) - Used to get Integer value.
[getJSONArray()](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getJSONArray(java.lang.String)) - Used to get Array from position.

---

Just like **JSONObject** [JSONArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html) does have several methods to retrieve value.

It's all about making sure either you're working with `JSONObject` or `JSONArray`.

---

Look on http://json-parser.com/51c495a8 to know the structure of your **JSON String**.

Answer (score 0):

Use json_decode with the second argument set to true, it'll give you an array.

```
json_decode($json, true);
```

that won't give you an StdClass.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse JSON String as follow but there is lots of foreach loop i hope it helps you..

```
  //Parse JSON String as array

  $res = json_decode($json_string, true);

  foreach ($json_a as $row => $value) {

      echo $row . "........";

      if(!is_array($value)){

           echo $value."</br>";     
      }

      else{

           foreach ($value as $k=>$v){

              echo "</br>........".$k."........</br>";

              foreach($v as $data=>$dv){

                   echo $data."....".$dv."</br>";

              }

          }
     }
 }
```

[image: This will return like below:]